# How to convert result of np.where to array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array from which I want to get the indices of the elements of interest by condition np.where:

```
diff = [19, 403472, 403491, 403491, 403491, 403491, 13, 403478, 13]
np.where(diff > np.average(diff))
```

As result I have tuple:

```
(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7], dtype=int64),)
```

But I want only array:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

And list() don't help.

Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: `where` produces a tuple, in this a 1 element tuple; that element is the array you want.  The rest is plain Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where(diff > np.average(diff))[0]`?

output:

`array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7])`

Comment: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7], dtype=int64)

Comment: a = np.where(diff > np.average(diff))[0]
a.append(8)
a #     I have error numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: yes, that's what you want, It is the ready-to-use array now.

Comment: I cant append new element to it

Comment: You want `array` or `list`? Your question says `array`. `array` doesn't have the `append` property. If `list`, use `list()`.

Comment: ohhh.... exactly